# Custom social share not opening in windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, share

I created a custom social sharing module based on **[this tutorial](http://dapperdeveloper.com/2015/01/23/creating-custom-social-share-buttons/)** and am trying to understand why mine open up in a new tab at full screen, but the tutorial's opens up in new windows at certain sizes.

I would prefer mine to open up the same way this tutorial does, but I'm not sure. I know there is a way I can do this with `JS` where I define the size of the window, but that doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution to me.

Appreciate the help!

**Here is the basic HTML of a link:**

```
<a class="fa fa-twitter share-base share-twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=the text')"></a>
```

and here is my **[module's prototype](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/xVzazo)**.

Comment: Like this `window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith beautiful, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the the size inside the `window.open` like this:

```
<a class="fa fa-twitter share-base share-twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=the text','','width=200,height=100')">test</a>
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1a8mpL75/1/